# Что делает команда "npm/yarn start" в React Native-приложении созданном с помощью "react-native init"?

Tags: react-native

Создал новый React-native проект с помощью команды:

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Скрипты как обычно называются короткими словами, не отвечающими на вопрос "что конкретно они делают?";  ответ на этот вопрос в отношении скрипта `start` находится где-то в глубинах документации.

Если его запустить, то будет примерно такое отображение в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Естественная реакция того, кто никогда не работал с React Native - "и чё теперь?!".

P. S. Не рекомендуйте мне Expo, если этот фреймворк не собирает приложения для Windows, macOS и Linux.

Comment: теперь открываем ещё одно командное окно и запускаем `npm run android`

Comment: @Spatz, благодарю Вас за комментарий! А почему нельзя сразу `npm run android` без `npm run start`?

Comment: Так построена система (по типу клиент-сервер)

Comment: Хорошо. Могу ли я Вас попросить оформить ответ с разъяснением того, что же конкретно делает `npm run start`? Я Вам дам очки репутации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе всё описано в [документации](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), надо только выбрать вариант `React Native CLI Quickstart` (по умолчанию выбран `Expo Quickstart`).

Запуск приложения состоит из двух этапов:

1. Запуск сервиса сборки *JavaScript* / *TypeScript* модулей

> `npx react-native start` (или просто `npm start`)

2. Запуск нативного приложения для платформ *Android* / *iOS*

> `npx react-native run-android` (или просто `npm run android`)
> на примере для Android.

Сборщик модулей [**Metro**](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/concepts/) работает на хост-компьютере и среди прочих возможностей обеспечивает поиск зависимостей, преобразование кода и *горячую перезагрузку*.

Нативное приложение работает на мобильном устройстве и для обеспечения сервисных функций системы разработчика поддерживает связь с хост-компьютером. При желании второй этап можно заменить, например можно открыть папку `android` из *Android Studio* и запустить приложение оттуда.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если возникают вопросы по сборке react native лучшего места чем исходники CLI не найти. В ответ на ваш вопрос можно почитать как реализована эта команда, она достаточно простая [react-native-cli/commands/start](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/packages/cli/src/commands/start/start.ts)

Comment: для того чтобы увидеть то, что видно по ссылке, достаточно сказать `npm start --help`

Comment: внутри есть ```import runServer from './runServer';``` и в нем как раз имплементация